# Example of a sample where mean, variance and median are equal

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

> Find examples of two samples: $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5)$ and $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4, Y_5, Y_6)$ where sample mean, sample variance and median are all equal to $2$.

After many failures, I managed to find the first sample:
$X = (0, 2, 2, 2, 4)$.

$$\bar{X} = \frac{0 + 2+ 2+ 2+4}{5} = 2$$

$$S_X^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left ( (0-2)^2 + 3\cdot(2-2)^2+ (4-2)^2 \right ) = 2$$

However, I struggle to find the second one. Is there any way to "see" this, without using the method of randomly guessing numbers and seeing if they fit? Especially since I also have to find another sample of size five, but this time the statistics have to equal 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y could be (0,1,2,2,3,4). I just wrote out a number line and tried to balance the numbers around 2. 
Your second problem can't be done. The numbers can't balance around 3 and have the squares sum to 12.

Comment: Could I do it with a biased variance estimator? Then the squares would have to sum to 15.

Comment: what do you mean by a biased variance estimator?

Comment: i.e. using $S_X^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ instead of $S_X^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$

Comment: I've done some hand calculations and I don't think the squares can sum to 15 or any other odd number

Comment: I think I found the other one: $X = (3 - \sqrt{6}, 3, 3, 3, 3 + \sqrt{6})$, the squares of their distances from the mean sum up to 12.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=6$ you know that their sum equals $12$ and the sum of their squares equals $34$. Not let three of them be $2$ and one of them zero.  Then solve the quadratic system 
$$y_1+y_6=6\quad\text{and}\quad y_1^2+y_6^2=32.$$